# Dos command to get IE Page source

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, dos

Is it possible to get the source of a webpage, which is currently opened in IE or chrome from command line or using a java code? I believe there has to be a way. If yes, how could we fetch the exact info of it as chrome and IE support multiple tabs.

I am trying to process content from hundreds of webpages, some of them automatically refresh at regular 15 sec interval. And some do not.

Yes, i could get the webpage source by using sockets or by using an instance of URLConnection class. However, it doesn't provide the default refresh functionality of a browser. The only option will be to hit the URL multiple times, which could be avoided if the default browsers refresh functionality could be utilized.

Also, It would be great, if the reader could comment on how to fill in text boxes using a program and submit the request from the browser. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could use the `Robot` class to send `Alt+V+C` to IE, which will open the source code page, then send `Ctrl+C` and access the clipboard from Java.

Comment: @ortis: I doubt that any browser responds to synthetic events :-/

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What is your use case? Maybe there is another way to achieve what you want?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla Chrome does. I wrote a small java code to refresh 2 tab constantly. Works well.

Comment: Hello Aaron, Would you please update on how you were able to extract this information?

Answer (score 1):

There are several "scraping" frameworks in Java.

I personally like **JSoup** a lot, because it is lightweight and compact in code.

```
  // get the source of a website in just 1 line of code.
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();

  // print all hyperlink paths.
  Elements links = doc.select("a[href$=.html]");
  for (Element lnk : links) System.out.println(lnk.attr("href"));
```

However it does not render javascript or anything like that. It's simple, fast but stupid.

I think you may prefer to use **HtmlUnit** instead, which is more like an invisible webbrowser. It gives you the possibility to even simulate click events on buttons, execute javascript, ... etc. You can make it mimic Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Comment: The primary requirement being to use the browsers inbuilt functionality and reduce the number of HTTP calls. i can fetch the page source as you said and could execute the links, but using javascript is not supported here.

Comment: Yes, so then HtmlUnit is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) WebDrivers - set of modifications/add-on's for desktop and phone browsers that allow you to fully control them from your code - including getting source of currently loaded page(using [getPageSource() method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource())), filling input's and submitting forms, selecting text, clicking some points, and almost just every other thing's that can be done in browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will be trying out the selenium now. Yours is the closest answer to my requirements. Request you to explain the features of selenium in more detail. It would be helpful to many. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple HTTP Client in order to get the source of your page using commons-httpclient.

Having you set up your libraries, you can use the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url); // http://www.google.com

client.executeMethod(method);

String result = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

In the result variable, you will get the source code of the page, in this case, the Google's main search page. So you can do whatever you want. For example, you can keep refreshing the page using a Java Thread and do whatever you want with the result.

You can find more information on [Commons HTTP-Client Page](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

Answer (score 0):

[Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) may help, if you mean "terminal" and not specifically the DOS operating system. There's also something called [bitsadmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362813(v=vs.85).aspx) (which I'm not familiar with), and I found this in a search too: [Jaunt - Java Web Scraping & Automation](http://jaunt-api.com/), if that'll help. I'm not a Java guy, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I have tried that long back. But it doesnt address my requirements. After many days of searching on net for an appropriate solution, had to post this question with bounty. Thanks for your response.